# phonegap custom icon + splashscreen does not work

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to add custom icon and splashscreen for Android by following [this](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html) guide but nothing works.

My steps:

- Add icons
- Change config.xml so the icons are there
- Do `phonegap build android`
- Copy apk and install in my android device

The icon is the same and no surprise I get no splashscreen, I can even know that there will be no effect before I install since `\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable` contains default icon instead of mine.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.coolapz.app"
    versionCode="110"
    version   = "1.1">

    <name>app name</name>
    <description>app desc</description>
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <!-- ALSO TRIED THIS, DIDN'T DO ANYTHING -->
    <!--
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    -->
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all splash screen and icon under res/hdpi and other...

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",5000);
```

And it works, but like this, result is:

1. Splash screen for 5 seconds
2. Black screen until the app is ready
3. index.html when app is ready

Comment: But isn't purpose of splash-screen is to be there until app is ready?

Comment: just put your splash and icon  under res folder in android...100 % it will work and also add above code